# Dynamically enabling/disabling button based from if statement Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, ionic-framework

I want to disable buttons based on my if statement. I get the data from firebase and based from that I will enable/disable the button.

Let say that on my First Quiz I pass it, I will enable the next lesson and so on. If the user did not pass the quiz the button is disabled.

On my Typescript:

```
this.currentUser = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
this.lessonStatus = this.af.object("/Quiz/" + this.currentUser + "/First_Quiz", { preserveSnapshot: true });
 this.lessonStatus2 = this.af.object("/Quiz/" + this.currentUser + "/Sec_Quiz", { preserveSnapshot: true });
 this.lessonStatus3 = this.af.object("/Quiz/" + this.currentUser + "/Third_Quiz", { preserveSnapshot: true });
 this.lessonStatus4 = this.af.object("/Quiz/" + this.currentUser + "/Fourth_Quiz", { preserveSnapshot: true });

this.lessonStatus.subscribe(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    this.arrayTest.push(snapshot.val());
  });
//Outputs "true"
  console.log(this.arrayTest[0].Passed)

  if (this.arrayTest[0].passed == true) {

    this.lessonUnlocked = [{
      name: "unlock",
      valid: true,
    }];

  }
  else {

    this.lessonUnlocked = [{
      name: "lock",
      valid: false,
    }];

  }
});
//It will be same here for lessonstatus 2 to 4.
```

On my HTML

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let x of lessonUnlocked">

<ion-item *ngIf = "x.valid == true">
<button [disabled]="x.valid" ion-item (click)="Lesson1()">
<ion-icon name="{{x.name}}"></ion-icon> Lesson1
</button>
</ion-item>

 <ion-item *ngIf = "x.valid == true">
<button  [disabled]="x.valid" ion-item (click)="Lesson2()">
<ion-icon name="{{x.name}}"></ion-icon> Lesson2
</button>
</ion-item>

<ion-item *ngIf = "x.valid == true">
<button ion-item (click)="Lesson3()">
<ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon> Lesson3
</button>
</ion-item>
```

The problem: it returns false even though my data in firebase is true. It seems that it does not execute the first if Statement:

```
 else {

    this.lessonUnlocked = [{
      name: "lock",
      valid: false,
    }];

  }
```

Comment: Could it be because you use lowercase `passed` in your if statement?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese Thanks, Mate! Did not notice that lol. So silly of me hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

> ApplicationRef.tick() - similar to Angular 1's $rootScope.$digest() --
>   i.e., check the full component tree
>
> ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() - similar to $scope.$digest() --
>   i.e., check only this component and its children

After you get you update your data from subscribe method, use one of these to update the view with new changes.